# What number should be in the place of "?"

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, number-sequence

I'm trying to solve this puzzle. Numbers are at triangle, and I have to solve ?-mark:

```
       5
     6   1
   7       2
  5  ?   7   5
```

Based on solutions it should be ?=7. But I don't understand the reason for this

I also put pic of it.[image: Triangle quiz]

Comment: There could be dozens of answers with a reasonable logic. For instance, it should be 2 as in every little triangle there are two numbers whose sum is the third.

Comment: Can you then name one explanation, why the answer would be seven?

Comment: What is the source for this puzzle? A textbook, competition, ... ?

Comment: Yes, for instance: every number should appear an odd number of times.

Comment: Not sure, sorry. My friend asked this.

Answer (score 3):

It is:

> 7. Start with $5,5,5$. The sum is $15$. Move each circle clockwise one step. You now have $1,7,7$, again the sum is $15$. Moving clockwise again you have $2,?,6$. For the sum to be $15$, $?=7$.